# Error while clicking links on highchart columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I get an error

`{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

While clicking on the link, I enabled for the columns in the column chart. What is the cause for this error and how do I overcome this error.

**My Series**

```
series: [{
            name: 'Capital',
            data: [1000000.00, 1000000.00, 1000000.00, 1000000.00, 900000.00],
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        }, {
            name: 'Material',
            data: [8753.15, 529.00, 5620.00, 35000.00, 30988.86]
        }, {
            name: 'HR',
            data: [66400.00, 320000.00, 488000.00, 48000.00, 512000.00]
        }, {
            name: 'Equipment',
            data: [0.00, 160000.00, 1600000.00, 32000.00, 64000.00]
        }, {
            name: 'Petty Cash',
            data: [10000.00, 100000.00, 100000.00, 10000.00, 150000.00]
        }],
```

**Plot options**

```
 plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (e) {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                             e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My consolidated code fiddled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/3TRL6/3/).

Is this the right way to provide links to navigate while clicking ?

Comment: You're going to _have_ to be more specific. Show some code, but I know this error from jsfiddle. You're probably submitting something from a fiddle. Use `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` to avoid this error

Comment: I have provided the code and a fiddled version too. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yes, I do use e.preventDefault(); but no luck.

Comment: I don't see you call the preventDefault and stopPropagation methods anywhere, nor do I see the error. Also: not sure if a `<script>` tag in jsFiddle does the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs:

1) in click event you are using this.options.url, which is undefined, while should be (according to your series configuration) `this.series.options.url`

2) Add point.events under plotOptions.series:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        console.log(this.series.options.url);
                        location.href = this.series.options.url;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And 'working' jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3TRL6/5/show/ - (works for Capital series). Full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3TRL6/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the code with jsFiddle, you might get this error "{"error": "Please use POST request"}", since you are requesting a non secure site "url:'**http**://www.google.com'" on jsFiddle which is secured i.e '**https**://jsfiddle.net/'. **Try replacing Http with Https**.

Please find jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ajaytripathi10/dk5ogkj9/1/

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.y:.1f}'
    },
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          console.log(this.options.url);
          location.href = this.options.url;
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```